# Pandas, compute many means with bootstrap confidence intervals for plotting

Tags: pandas, data-structures, nested-loops, confidence-interval, statistics-bootstrap

I want to compute means with bootstrap confidence intervals for some subsets of a dataframe; the ultimate goal is to produce bar graphs of the means with bootstrap confidence intervals as the error bars. My data frame looks like this:

```
ATG12 Norm     ATG5 Norm    ATG7 Norm    Cancer Stage    
5.55           4.99         8.99         IIA
4.87           5.77         8.88         IIA
5.98           7.88         8.34         IIC
```

The subsets I'm interested in are every combination of Norm columns and cancer stage. I've managed to produce a table of means using:

```
df.groupby('Cancer Stage')['ATG12 Norm', 'ATG5 Norm', 'ATG7 Norm'].mean()
```

But I need to compute bootstrap confidence intervals to use as error bars for each of those means using the approach described here: http://www.randalolson.com/2012/08/06/statistical-analysis-made-easy-in-python/ 
It boils down to:

```
import scipy
import scikits.bootstraps as bootstraps
CI = bootstrap.ci(data=Series, statfunction=scipy.mean)
# CI[0] and CI[1] are your low and high confidence intervals
```

I tried to apply this method to each subset of data with a nested-loop script:

```
for i in data.groupby('Cancer Stage'):
    for p in i.columns[1:3]: # PROBLEM!!
        Series = i[p]
        print p
        print Series.mean()
        ci = bootstrap.ci(data=Series, statfunction=scipy.mean)
```

Which produced an error message

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute called 'columns'
```

Not knowing what "tuples" are, I have some reading to do but I'm worried that my current approach of nested for loops will leave me with some kind of data structure I won't be able to easily plot from. I'm new to Pandas so I wouldn't be surprised to find there's a simpler, easier way to produce the data I'm trying to graph. Any and all help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Is this code working on your machine? Don't know where you got "scikits.bootstraps". Is it "scikits.bootstrap" (without de "s") from https://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap? If so, please correct the post accordingly to avoid confusion! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you iterate over the groupby-object is wrong! When you use groupby(), your data frame is sliced along the values in your groupby-column(s), together with these values as group names, forming a so-called "tuple":
`(name, dataforgroup)`. The correct recipe for iterating over groupby-objects is

```
for name, group in data.groupby('Cancer Stage'):
    print name
    for p in group.columns[0:3]:
    ...
```

Please read more about the groupby-functionality of pandas [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) and go through the [python-reference](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) in order to understand what tuples are!

Grouping data frames and applying a function is essentially done in one statement, using the `apply`-functionality of pandas:

```
cols=data.columns[0:2]
for col in columns:
    print data.groupby('Cancer Stage')[col].apply(lambda x:bootstrap.ci(data=x, statfunction=scipy.mean))
```

does everything you need in one line, and produces a (nicely plotable) series for you

**EDIT**:
I toyed around with a data frame object I created myself:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(24), 'B':list('aabb') * 6, 'C':range(15,39)})
for col in ['A', 'C']:
    print df.groupby('B')[col].apply(lambda x:bootstrap.ci(data=x.values))
```

yields two series that look like this:

```
B
a    [6.58333333333, 14.3333333333]
b                      [8.5, 16.25]

B
a    [21.5833333333, 29.3333333333]
b            [23.4166666667, 31.25]
```

Comment: I tried your first suggestion:

    for name, group in data.groupby('Cancer Stage'):
    print name
    for p in group.columns[2:8]:
        Series = i[p] # PROBLEM!
        print p
        print Series.mean()
        ci = bootstrap.ci(data=Series, statfunction=scipy.mean)
        print ci[0], ci[1]

and got an error that read: "TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not unicode" so I guess I need to find a way to get integers to give as input

Comment: The second suggestion didn't work either and gave a "TypeError: unhashable type" which, unlike the error for your first suggestion, I don't even have a clue of how to fix. Thanks for showing me a path to follow!

Comment: Sorry, I am more used to pandas, than I am to the bootstrap-functionality. wait a sec...

Comment: For me, it works. Unfortunately, I have no data lying around I need to bootstrap ;) ... I don't know where your error comes from right now, look at my edited recipe and adjust it to your needs maybe...

Comment: It seems that the second error has to do with pandas and bootstrap not working well together. I would use the second recipe, iterating over every column of the data frame, and computing the bootstrap confidence intervals individually for every column