# bootstrap on a groupby object in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, statistics-bootstrap

I have multiple time series with observations as rows (indexed by Timestamp, n > 5000) and variables as columns (n=419).  I am selecting *N* percent inclusion in the timeseries, then calling groupby to group by year.  What I want is the mean, standard deviation, and then the 95% confidence intervals for each year.  I can get mean and std easy enough with the code below, but I need to call a separate bootstrap function to get the 95% CI for each year and each group:

This is a glimpse of what the grouped data looks like: (there are 86 rows for 2013 and 28 columns, and the data begins in 1970s).  I need to use 'bootsrap' for each column in grouped for each year in grouped.

```
for year, group in grouped:
print year
print group

2013
                  101        102        103        104       105        109     
2013-04-02    3162.84    4136.02   77124.56       0.00    973.18    9731.81   
2013-04-04    1033.81    5464.44   87283.30    3692.19   4282.94     295.37   
2013-04-04     640.75    4164.87  131033.14    2563.00   1121.31     961.12   
2013-04-10     246.87    4196.84   88380.57    4443.72    493.75    1234.37   
2013-04-13       0.00    8300.49  114291.42   10003.16    212.83    6385.00
```

`
    And here are my functions for groupby and bootstrap:

```
def gbY_20pct(nm): # sort into 20% timeseries inclusion, groupby year, take mean for year
        nm1=nm.replace('0', np.nan) # remove 0 for logical count
        coun=nm1.count(axis=0,numeric_only=True)
        pct=(coun/len(nm1)) *100
        pCount=pct.loc[pct >= 20]
        nm1=nm.loc[:, pCount.index]
        grouped = nm1.groupby(nm1.index.map(lambda x: x.year))
        yrly=grouped.mean().astype(int)
        yrly_coun=grouped.count().astype(int)
        yrly_std=grouped.std().astype(int)
        yrly_max=grouped.max().astype(int)
        yrM1=yrly.join(yrly_std, lsuffix=' mean', rsuffix=' std', how='outer')
        yrM2=yrly_max.join(yrly_coun, lsuffix=' max', rsuffix=' count', how='outer')
        data=yrM1.join(yrM2, how='outer')
        return data
```

`

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr  
def bootstrap(data, num_samples, statistic, alpha):
    """Returns bootstrap estimate of 100.0*(1-alpha) CI for statistic."""
    n = len(data)
    idx = npr.randint(0, n, (num_samples, n))
    samples = data[idx]
    stat = np.sort(statistic(samples, 1))
    return (stat[int((alpha/2.0)*num_samples)],
            stat[int((1-alpha/2.0)*num_samples)])
```

To test the code, I am calling it manually (grouped has been defined and the function has not closed)

```
from bootstrap import bootstrap
low, high = bootstrap(grouped, 100000, np.mean, 0.05)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-49-cd362c7908d1>", line 1, in <module>
    low, high = bootstrap(grouped, 100000, np.mean, 0.05)

  File "bootstrap.py", line 14, in bootstrap

  File "C:\Users\ryan.morse\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py", line 2991, in __getitem__
    bad_keys = list(set(key).difference(self.obj.columns))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The problem comes from the `samples = data[idx]` line. I suspect I need to be more specific than using 'grouped' for the data field in bootstrap, but I am unsure how to do this.  Do I need to apply this as a lambda function?  Or maybe with a for loop?  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

After looking at this page: [Pandas, compute many means with bootstrap confidence intervals for plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685506/pandas-compute-many-means-with-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-for-plotting) and trying the scikit bootstrap function https://scikits.appspot.com/bootstrap, I have tested the function defined above and found it MUCH faster with comparable results.

---

Edit:

I am thinking that something like this might work, but I still can't get the syntax correct:

```
groups=dict(list(grouped)) # this allows me to visualize the data and call values

for key, value in groups.iteritems():
low_i, high_i = bootstrap(groups.values(), 100000, np.mean, 0.05) 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-36-7a8e261d656e>", line 2, in <module>
    low_i, high_i=bootstrap(groups.values(), 10000, np.mean, 0.05)

  File "<ipython-input-15-3ce4acd651dc>", line 7, in bootstrap
    samples = data[idx]

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

I'm not sure how to call 'data' for the bootstrap function, and also how to iterate over all years and keep low and high for all years (either in the same dataframe or in 2 separate ones).

Any help would be most appreciated...

---

EDIT 2 I can use a lambda function just as easily, however I can't seem to get the proper output:

```
for col, group in nm1.groupby(nm1.index.year):
    lo,hi=bootstrap(group,1000, np.mean, 0.05)

lo
Out[117]: 
array([ 0.05713616,  0.30724739,  0.39592714,  0.55113183,  0.68623155,
        0.69493923,  0.73513661,  0.84086099,  0.85882618,  0.86698939,
        0.99399694,  1.04415927,  1.06553914,  1.11306698,  1.15344871,
        1.27943327,  1.43275895,  1.81076036,  2.21647657,  2.37724615,
        2.39004626,  2.43154256,  2.89940325,  3.02234954,  3.30773642,
        3.96535146,  3.98973744,  4.38873853])

hi
Out[118]: 
array([ 0.20584822,  0.38832222,  0.42140066,  0.48615202,  0.59686031,
        0.67388397,  0.84269082,  0.84532503,  0.87078368,  0.9033272 ,
        0.90765817,  0.97523759,  0.99186096,  1.01668772,  1.06681722,
        1.18205259,  1.38524423,  1.79908484,  2.22314773,  2.33789105,
        2.5521743 ,  2.64242269,  2.88851233,  2.94387756,  3.44294791,
        3.63914938,  3.99185026,  4.36450246])
```

If this had worked, I would have lo and hi for each of the 28 columns for each of the 33 years, instead I have an ordered array of numbers that do not seem to have any real value... this is a snippet of `yrly` which contains the log transformed groupby means for each year, the bootrapped CIs shouls be close to these numbers, unlike the above arrays.

```
           101       102       103       104       105       109       135  
1978  3.416638  3.701268  3.828442  2.911944  2.687491  2.076515  1.232035   
1979  2.710939  3.172061  4.234109  1.666818  3.390646  1.355179  3.003813   
1980  2.652617  2.375495  3.316380  1.101594  2.220028  1.195449  1.998862   
1981  3.363424  3.485015  3.441784  2.242618  2.256745  1.719140  1.150454   
1982  2.791865  2.019883  4.093960  1.038226  2.106627  1.180935  2.456144   
1983  2.597307  2.213450  4.458691  1.274352  2.820910  1.705242  3.452762   
1984  3.042197  4.023952  3.816964  2.499883  2.445258  1.769485  1.690180   
1985  2.669850  2.162608  3.600731  1.400102  1.845218  1.234235  2.517108   
1986  3.597527  2.763436  2.790792  1.410343  2.116275  1.042812  1.528532
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all that, the answer I came up with is:

```
import scipy.stats
ci = grouped.aggregate(lambda x: scipy.stats.sem(x, ddof=1) * 1.96) #use mean +(-) ci to get 95% conf interval
```

It turns out I don't really need to bootstrap the data so I can just estimate the 95% confidence interval based on the standard error of the mean multiplied by the 0.975 quantile of the normal distribution, assuming that the data are normally distributed (but that is another issue...).

```
           101       102       103       104       105       109       135
1978  0.230630  0.191651  0.168648  0.282588  0.237939  0.288924  0.257476   
1979  0.192579  0.147305  0.120740  0.225826  0.145646  0.266530  0.199315   
1980  0.189258  0.195263  0.182756  0.166479  0.166401  0.172550  0.189483   
1981  0.200727  0.169663  0.184478  0.232392  0.198591  0.230457  0.194084   
1982  0.271740  0.267881  0.164450  0.248718  0.246636  0.260973  0.253430   
1983  0.253495  0.279114  0.116744  0.266888  0.236672  0.317195  0.155766
```

Comment: The data don't have to be normally distributed, since the sampling distribution of the mean is normally distributed by the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)