# How to run a bootstrap average over a table of variables in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, average, statistics-bootstrap

I am wondering how to run a **bootstrap average** code over a table of values where each column needs to be bootstrapped individually? And then what would be especially helpful is if the output of results could be output into another table that summarises results.

Specifically, I am trying to do this for a series of element data (see below).

```js
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('element_data.csv')
df
```

[image: output of df showing element concentration data]

Any help with this would be a huuuge help to not only myself but also to all those others trying to run lot's of bootstraps (of which there are plenty!)

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685506/pandas-compute-many-means-with-bootstrap-confidence-intervals-for-plotting ?

Comment: Please [create a reproducible copy of the DataFrame with `df.head(13).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413246/how-to-provide-a-copy-of-your-dataframe-with-to-clipboard), [edit] the question, and paste the clipboard into a code block. Add data as text, because [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). It is likely the question will be down-voted. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.